# How to get signal strenght of wifi

Tags: wireless

I want to get the wireless signal on a terminal, but only the signal.
So no extra info, just the connection speed.

It would help a lot!

Edit:

`iwconfig` Returns this:

```
lo        no wireless extensions.

eth0      no wireless extensions.

eth1      IEEE 802.11abg  ESSID:"Goeggies"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.437 GHz  Access Point: B4:82:FE:93:DA:BC   
          Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
```

Comment: wavemon is easily installed and provides a graphical display.

Answer (score 2):

Watch out, signal level and connection speed aren't necessarily correlated.

Use the `iwconfig` command:

```
wlan2     IEEE 802.11abgn  ESSID:"something"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:5.745 GHz  Access Point: 60:AA:4C:D4:53:FC   
          Bit Rate=144.4 Mb/s   Tx-Power=15 dBm   
          Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=64/70  Signal level=-46 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:381146  Invalid misc:1531   Missed beacon:0
```

"Bit rate" indicates the actual transfer speed, while "Link Quality" and "Signal Level" tell you how strong the signal is.

Comment: They why not `iwconfig | grep level`, or `iwconfig | grep Signal`? ;-)

Comment: iwconfig doesn't return anything with wlan2, see edit

Comment: Your wireless interface is `eth1`, `wlan2` was just an example :) If some specific item of information is not available, maybe your driver doesn't report it :(